# Deleting words that appear multiple times in a file

Tags: python, string

How can I delete words that appear multiple times in a file and just keep the first one and delete the clones.

Comment: Can you search/replace with a regular expression?

Comment: The algorithm depends on the nature of the file: very very big or reasonable size that allows to load the content in memory ?

Answer (score 3):

A simple algorithm is to just iterate over all words in the input, adding each one to a set of words you've seen before. If the word was already in the set, remove it.

Here's an example:

```
seen_words = set()
for word in words:
    if word not in seen_words:
        print word
        seen_words.add(word)
```

Comment: It can't be applied to the treatment of a file because of the problem of lines to keep with the newlines

Comment: Yes, this example only deals with the elimination of duplicates. Dividing up the input into words and reassembling the words back again is a separate concern, and Stack Overflow isn't a please-write-my-code-for-me type of site.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a dictionary like this:

```
mydict = {}
mylist = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5]
for item in mylist:
  mydict[item] = ""
for item in mydict:
  print item
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But of course you would need to integrate that into file reading/writing.

Comment: why do you not just use a set?

Comment: 1357 He doesn't want to print , he wants to correct the content of a file

Comment: Quote from my post: "But of course you would need to integrate that into file reading/writing."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set:

set('these are all the words the words all are these'.split())

output:
'these', 'the', 'all', 'are', 'words'

Comment: Set does not preserve the order!

Answer (score 0):

```
fileText = "some words with duplicate words"
fileWords = fileText.split(" ")
output = fileWords[0]
words = [output]
for word in fileWords:
    if word not in words:
        output += " "+word
        words.append(word)
```

Comment: Each execution of ``output += " "+word`` consists in creating a new object having the values of output," " and word concatenated. If the file is big, it represents a lot of work for the intepreter. Moreover, spliting according to " " gives strings that may have newlines in them . So 'sun\nsea' will be a word, and when 'sun' or 'sea' will come in the middle of a line , it won't be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not EXTREMELY big,

```
word='word'
data=open("file").read()
ind = data.find(word)
print data[:ind+len(word)] + data[ind:].replace(word,"")
```